# Вывести отрицательное число из массива, встречающееся только 1 раз

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int max(int, int); //    <<<<<<<<<<Обьявляем функцияю до её использования

void main()//--> Начало главной функции !!!
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");                
int mas[15] = {-1,10,3,-6,10,-8,7,-1,6,7,7,6,4,9,-8};       // <<Массив
int min = 0;
int min2 = 0;                                           // <<Минимальное число число
int counter = 0;                                        // <<Счётчик поBторений
//->
cout<<"Вводим массив\n";
min2 = mas[0]; //-1                                 //Присваиваем минимальному числу первый элемент массива
for(int e=0;e<14;e++){                          //< пробегаем цикл гарантированно все 15 элементов
while(min>mas[e]){                                  //Если минимальное число меньше находящегося в массиве, тогда присвоить ему это число
counter++;                                          // Увеличить счётчик на 1
min = mas[e];   
if (counter=1){
min = min2;
cout<<min;
counter=0;
break;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////<<<<<<<<<<<<<   Найдено
}
else
break;

}
}
}                                   //<--------------|конец главной функции         !!!
```

Неправильно считает, непойму почему, уже запутался, помогите пажалуйста выдаёт -1, -1, -1, если есть лучший алгоритм, напишите, будет лучше

Comment: @IgorbShum, во первых Вы написали 

    if (counter=1)

вместо

    if (counter==1)

чего Вы очевидно хотели,

а во вторых, дело даже не в этом. Просто Ваш алгоритм не решает данную задачу. 

--

Наверное самым простым (но не эффективным) способом будет подсчет количества вхождений в массив каждого отрицательного элемента. Т.е.

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       if (mas[i] < 0 && count(mas,n,mas[i]) == 1) {
          cout << "Found " << mas[i] << " in pos " << i << '\n';
          break;
       }
    }
    if (i == n)
       cout << "Not found\n";

А функцию `count()` напишите сами.

Answer (score 2):

Есть ошибки.

```
for(int e=0;e<14;e++){                          //< пробегаем цикл гарантированно все 15 элементов
```

Не 15, а 14 проходов получится. От 0 до 13. 14 по условию "<14" не пройдёт.

`if (counter=1)`

^ Здесь должно быть "==", иначе это условие будет выполняться **всегда**.

Вообще много что непонято зачем, вот например рабочий вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()//--> Начало главной функции !!!
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");                
int mas[15] = {-1,10,3,-6,10,-8,7,-1,6,7,7,6,4,9,-8};       // <<Массив
//->
for(int e=0;e<15;e++){                          //< пробегаем цикл гарантированно все 15 элементов
bool unique=true; // уникален ли элемент
if( mas[e] >= 0 ) continue; // Пропускаем неотрицательные элементы
for(int f=0;f<15;f++){
    if(f==e) continue; // Пропуск самого себя
    if(mas[e]==mas[f])
    {
        unique = false; // Найден дубликат
        break;
    }
}
if( unique ) cout << mas[e] << endl; // Выводим отрицательный элемент, уникальный в массиве
}
return 0;
}
```